# When did Spider-Man get his mechanical web thrower?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-homecoming, spider-man-2

Peter Parker was bitten by a spider. Since then (after some biological advancements), Spider-Man was able to throw web-ropes for swinging and whatever purposes. It was [*Spider-Man 2*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_2) when it was still his biological arm.

Now I'm watching [*Spider-Man: Homecoming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Homecoming) which shows his mechanical arm is upgraded by Stark Industries.

So when was his biological spider capability changed into mechanical one?

Comment: You realize there are now three Spider-Man movie continuities (two of which are now defunct), right? The *Spider-Man 2* you mentioned isn't the same universe as *Homecoming*.

Comment: Answer here might help [Why does the Amazing Spider Man not have the natural power to shoot web?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8168/why-does-the-amazing-spider-man-not-have-the-natural-power-to-shoot-web)

Answer (score 6):

#### In the comics, way before he could naturally shoot webs; in the movies, he always uses them, or never uses them - it depends what movie your watching.

In the original *Amazing Spider-Man* comics, web shooters were a device Peter Parker created, in order to complement his new-found abilities; his ability to shoot webs are almost *always* a result of this device.

The Sam Raimi trilogy, the three starring Tobey Maguire, was based on a script that was initially written by James Cameron. [James Cameron had the brilliant idea that "organic web shooters" made more sense](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/8193/47313), and thus depicted them as such. This would later be adapted into the comic books, where in Peter Parker goes through more transformation, and grows organic web shooters; however, in the movie storyline, Spider-Man is given organic web shooters from the start. Regardless, in almost *all* depictions, the web-shooters are actual gadgets.

The gadget web-shooters make a return in 2012's [The Amazing Spider-Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0948470/). Once again, this is a different universe to the Tobey Maguire Spider-Man and Homecoming. In Homecoming, this device is created by Peter and improved by Tony Stark<sup>1</sup>. *Again*, this is a completely differant universe - the *"Marvel Cinematic Universe"*. It has no canonical connection to *The Amazing Spider-Man* movies, or the *Spider-Man* movies created by Sam Raimi.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Thanks to *cde* for clearing that up.</sub>

Comment: Homecoming's web shooters were created by Parker, not Tony. He just improved them.

Comment: @Gnemlock Maybe it's just me, but I keep having to read the first sentence multiple times to understand what it is saying. Mostly because it only makes sense when immediately following the question in the title. I keep expecting it to say "In the comics, way before he could shoot webs, [something that happens in the comics before he could shoot webs]." I feel like my suggested edit was much easier to read. Or I'm sure there's some other similar edit that could have worked better than either one.

Comment: @Gnemlock I still can't figure out if the "naturally" in the first sentence is meant to describe shooting webs naturally/organically, or if it is meant as to describe how it makes sense that the movies do what they do. If the former, then at least the comma before "naturally" needs to be removed. Are main sentences as answers not supposed to be stand-alone complete thoughts?

Comment: Similarly, when I made the edit, I had been reading "in the comics" as part of the answer to when it happened ("it happened in the comics"). But now it seems more likely you meant to give a 2 part answer; "when it happened in the comics" and "when it happened in the movies". This ambiguity may have caused my edit to misrepresent your answer.

Comment: @GendoIkari, I have moved the word "naturally"; the rest of the title remains *as is*. The purpose of a semi colon (;) is to break apart sentences that have *connection* but are not *directly related*. I feel the use of 'comics ; movies' appropriately separates them from each other.

Answer (score 1):

Spider-Man has normally always had mechanical web shooters. Since he was created as a comic character, and in multiple cartoons and movies. The organic web shooters were invented in 2002 as a reimagining of Spider-Man by director Sam Rami. See  http://www.cbr.com/follow-the-path-spider-mans-organic-webshooters/ This was later implemented in the Spider-Man comics in 2004 So it would match the current movie version of Spider-Man at the time the series was made. It was a highly contentious change, for both the movie and comics. Marvel has since implemented many changes to their comics to follow the movies (Spiderman and most of the Avengers in the comics now resemble their movie counterparts, introduction of movie only characters like Coulson into the comic universe).

***The Amazing Spider-Man trilogy and Homecoming go back to the original design where Peter Parker uses Mechanical web shooters.*** The biological ones are the odd man out. Each of these movie series are a different take on Spider-Man, and are not in continuity with each other.

Homecoming implements part of a different take on Spider-Man, where the comic event Civil War included the Iron Spider. This version had Peter Parker use a suit created by Tony Stark, which included all sorts of Iron Man/StarkTech upgrades. Tony gives it to Parker because Parker sides with Tony's pro-registration side of super heroes. Much like he does in the movie Captain  America, Civil War, which adapts the Iron Man vs Capt. Storyline of the comic event of the same name.