# What is Spider-Man wearing on his hand?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Towards the beginning of *Avengers: Infinity War*, Peter Parker is on a school bus. When Peter notices alien ship in the sky, he immediately asks the kid in front of him to create a distraction. The kid makes a distraction.

Then Peter places something (I think a mechanical device) on his wrist and goes outside of the bus. What is that device?

When did Spider-Man start using these devices for web-slinging? I thought Spider-Man can shoot webs from his hand biologically. Isn't it?

Comment: “I thought spider-man can shoot webs from his hand biologically” — not in these movies he can’t. (See *Captain America: Civil War* and *Spider-Man: Homecoming*). He did in [the Sami Raimi Spider-Man trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_in_film#Sam_Raimi_films), and [Spider-Man 2099](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_2099) does.

Comment: It's well worth noting that Spider-Man had NEVER been able to shoot webs organically until the first Raimi Spider-Man film. Web shooters are an *essential* part of the character. They show that Peter is a genius apart from his spider powers.

Comment: Related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/76226/when-did-spider-man-get-his-mechanical-web-thrower

Comment: J Micheal Staczynski retconned spiderman to have magic based powers sometime between 2001&2007.  The retcon didn't stick.  There was a "What If" issue where Flash Thompson becomes spiderman instead of Peter Parker.  He outperforms Peter until he dies fighting the Vulture because he didn't have Peter's ability to make web shooters.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**What is that device?**

That device is called a [Web-Shooter](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Web-Shooters) making him able to shoot webs.

**When did Spider-Man start using these devices for web-slinging?**

In this continuity, he never got organic web shooting ability with the bite and can only shoot webs using this device. You might be confusing this version with [Sam Raimi films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_in_film#Sam_Raimi_films).

There are multiple continuities in Spider-Man films and only the Sam Raimi films have organic web shooting ability, not the rest. Even in *The Amazing Spider-Man* continuity, he didn't have organic abilities and used similar devices. Refer to [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8168/why-does-the-amazing-spider-man-not-have-the-natural-power-to-shoot-web) for that.

Comment: I believe the Sam Raimi films were actually the *first* instance of Spider Man being able to naturally shoot webbing. I recall researching for another answer, and finding that this was only added to the comics *after* the Tobey Maguire films.

Comment: Couldn't he use organic webs during those times he was possessed by the Venom symbiote or turned into Man-Spider before that?

Comment: “I believe the Sam Raimi films were actually the first instance of Spider Man being able to naturally shoot webbing” — I think so too, although [Spider-Man 2099](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_2099) did it back in 1992.

Comment: @nick012000 The suit shot webs, not PP?  So, sortof?

Comment: @nick012000: That highly depends on whether you consider the venom/suit a tool or not. It's highly likely that the Venom suit produced the webs. I seem to remember Peter commenting that the venom-webs were considerably stronger than his own.